# how to send whole array to servlet and how to access it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, jqgrid

I am trying to get all jqgrid data in one array and sending to servelet,so far I am try with this-
                   var rows= jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getRowData');
                    var paras=new Array();

```
                for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
                {
                    var row=rows[i];
                    paras.push($.param(row));
                    //alert(paras[i]);
                }
                alert(paras);
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JQGridServlet?action=arraydata&paras="+paras,
                data: paras.join('and'),
                success: function(msg)
                {
                  alert(msg);
                }
                 });
```

but it send only first 'srno'.not whole array.
please any body suggest me to how to send array to servlet and how to access it on servlet.

Comment: data has to be an object with key value pairs `data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }`.

Comment: can you post your sample array data?

Comment: sample array data means what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var griddata= $( "#list" ).getRowData();
                var model = {
                    grid: griddata
                };

                var paras= JSON.stringify( model );

                alert(paras);
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "JQGridServlet?action=arraydata&paras="+paras,
                data: paras.join('and'),
                success: function(msg)
                {
                  alert(msg);
                }
                 });
```

Comment: Check what is received in the servlet.

Comment: Its not go in side the servlet.

Comment: if(request.getParameter("action").equals("arraydata"))
 {
      String data[] = request.getParameterValues("paras");
      System.out.println(data);
      if (data != null) 
      {
           for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
           {
                out.println(data[i]);
           }
      }
      out.println(data);
  }

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include the html part and servlet part to get a good answer.

Comment: what do you mean? if any other method to access the array in servlet then please tell me !!

Comment: put a dummy value in 'paras' and check whether it reaches servlet. If it does, the problem is in your html part. You have to post the jqgrid code in your question Please dont post it as a comment. Instead, edit your question.